# SwiftData issue with relationship

Tags: swiftui, swift-data

I have 2 classes and a relation from one to another. During runtime i get a error..."Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x233cd16e4)" Is there any solution to this error...

```
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
final class Main {
    var name: String
    var limit: Double
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade)
    var trans: [Child] = []
    
    init(name: String, limit: Double, trans: [Child]) {
        self.name = name
        self.limit = limit
        self.trans = trans
    }
}

@Model
final class Child {
    var trip: String
    var distance: Double

    init(trip: String, distance: Double) {
        self.trip = trip
        self.distance = distance
    }
}
```

The above is my code.... When i checked with postman for data i get all data but in the app it crashes...

```
{
    @storageRestrictions(accesses: _$backingData, initializes: _trans)
        init(initialValue) {
                    _$backingData.setValue(forKey: \.patient, to: initialValue)
                    _trans = _SwiftDataNoType()
        }

    get {
                    _$observationRegistrar.access(self, keyPath: \.trans)
                    return self.getValue(forKey: \.trans)
        }

    set {
                    _$observationRegistrar.withMutation(of: self, keyPath: \.trans) {
                            self.setValue(forKey: \.trans, to: newValue)
                    }
        }
}
```

I am trying to get data from a server via API call

Comment: The second code sample isn't really relevant, what is more interesting is how you create your objects and set the Child objects to a Main object.

Comment: The second block of code is where the error is shown... 

Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x233cd16e4)

Comment: It's still not interesting because the cause of the error is elsewhere.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks for the input.. Will recheck and revert ..

Comment: @Krish, Did you find any solution for this error ? I am also facing same error

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue.
I believe it occurs when attempting to insert/update multiple objects simultaneously. To resolve this, I recommend disabling autosave and manually saving after downloading and inserting/updating all data:

```
.modelContainer(for: Main.self, isAutosaveEnabled: false)

...

try modelContext.save()
```

This approach should help mitigate the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, the problem lied in the inability to read model data without prior saving it in the SwiftData container/model context. Therefore, the necessary steps are as follows:

- Avoid using the decoded API data model directly.
- First, **save the data in the container**.
- Retrieve and use the data from the container.

---

### Save Data

```
@Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
modelContext.insert(mainModel)
```

### Retrieve Data

```
@Query private var mainModels: [MainModel]
```

if you want to keep only one set of data in your modelContext, then you will need to delete previous record and then insert the model.